# Joining the tables.Aggregating and consolidating the counts

Tags: sql, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwT4f.gif)I have two tables

Table 1-qualified players

```
Id_sequence         
121             
345             
765
```

Table 2 - All enteries related to players    Note :there are only 6 game_ids  1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,2c

```
id_sequence player_id   game_id phone_no    
121     aaa     1a      111111111       
131     aaa     1b      111222111       
141     aaa     1a      111112222       
345     bbb     2a      222222222       
656     bbb     2c      222211122       
789     bbb     1c      222211122       
632     bbb     2b      222222222       
765     ccc     2b      333333333       
897     ddd     1a      444444444       
433     ddd     2c      555555444
```

Expected Output:

```
select all id_sequence from Table 1 and join Table 2.
```

Then select all other data related to that player_id then aggregate and consolidate the counts

```
player_id game id_1a game id_1b game id_1c game id_2a game id_2b game id_2c no_of _phones
aaa     2   1                                   3
bbb                       1           1                    1            1       2
ccc                                  1              1
```

Currently,I am creating a table 3 that stores the player_id obtained from joining table 1  and table 2 .Then again joining table 3 and 2.
Any thoughts and ideas will greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data (see also: [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a1eb629dc30eb67d7b74b071bd85ebf9))

```
SQL> select * from ae;
ID_SEQUENCE  PLAYER_ID  GAME_ID  PHONE_NO   
121          aaa        1a       111111111  
131          aaa        1b       111222111  
141          aaa        1a       111112222  
345          bbb        2a       222222222  
656          bbb        2c       222211122  
789          bbb        1c       222211122  
632          bbb        2b       222222222  
765          ccc        2b       333333333  
897          ddd        1a       444444444  
433          ddd        2c       555555444
```

Query

```
select
  dt1.*
, dt2.no_of_phones
from (
  (
    select game_id, player_id
    from ae 
  ) pivot  
    (
      count( game_id ) for game_id in 
      (
        '1a' as "game id_1a"
      , '1b' as "game id_1b" 
      , '1c' as "game id_1c"
      , '2a' as "game id_2a"
      , '2b' as "game id_2b"
      , '2c' as "game id_2c"
     )
  )
) dt1 join ( 
  select 
    player_id
  , count( phone_no ) no_of_phones
  from ae
  group by player_id
) dt2
  on dt1.player_id = dt2.player_id
order by dt1.player_id
;
```

Result

```
PLAYER_ID  game id_1a  game id_1b  game id_1c  game id_2a  game id_2b  game id_2c  NO_OF_PHONES  
aaa        2           1           0           0           0           0           3             
bbb        0           0           1           1           1           1           4             
ccc        0           0           0           0           1           0           1             
ddd        1           0           0           0           0           1           2
```

Comment: How can I join Table one(qualified players, containing only id_sequence) to second table and then run above mentioned query?

Comment: Just add {1} the id_sequence column into the SELECT clause of dt1, 
and {2} another JOIN plus ON clause for the "qualified_players" table ( see dbfiddle @ http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b9627af0eeadee5a65c2572c840b26a )
- Notice that you will lose some of the "game" information, as your qualified_players sample table only contains 3 id_sequence numbers.

Comment: That's great.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A PIVOT should take care of it

```
SQL> create table t1 ( id int);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t1 values (121             );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (345             );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (765 );

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create table t2 ( id int, player varchar2(10), game varchar2(10), phone int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t2 values (121     ,'aaa' ,    '1a'  ,    111111111);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (131     ,'aaa' ,    '1b'  ,    111222111  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (141     ,'aaa' ,    '1a'  ,    111112222  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (345     ,'bbb' ,    '2a'  ,    222222222  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (656     ,'bbb' ,    '2c'  ,    222211122  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (789     ,'bbb' ,    '1c'  ,    222211122  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (632     ,'bbb' ,    '2b'  ,    222222222  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (765     ,'ccc' ,    '2b'  ,    333333333  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (897     ,'ddd' ,    '1a'  ,    444444444  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (433     ,'ddd' ,    '2c'  ,    555555444);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   (SELECT player, game, phone
  3          FROM   t2)
  4  PIVOT  (count(phone) AS cnt FOR (game) IN ('1a','1b','2a','2b','3a','3c'));

PLAYER       '1a'_CNT   '1b'_CNT   '2a'_CNT   '2b'_CNT   '3a'_CNT   '3c'_CNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
aaa                 2          1          0          0          0          0
bbb                 0          0          1          1          0          0
ddd                 1          0          0          0          0          0
ccc                 0          0          0          1          0          0

4 rows selected.
```

Addenda to get NO_PHONES

```
SQL>     SELECT *
  2      FROM   (SELECT player, game, phone, count( distinct phone) over ( partition by player ) as no_phones
  3              FROM   t2)
  4      PIVOT  (count(phone) AS cnt FOR (game) IN ('1a','1b','2a','2b','3a','3c'));

PLAYER      NO_PHONES   '1a'_CNT   '1b'_CNT   '2a'_CNT   '2b'_CNT   '3a'_CNT   '3c'_CNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
ccc                 1          0          0          0          1          0          0
ddd                 2          1          0          0          0          0          0
aaa                 3          2          1          0          0          0          0
bbb                 2          0          0          1          1          0          0
```

Comment: How would you add the "no_of_phones" (total per player) column? With a join?

Comment: I've made an addenda to the SQL

Comment: Cheers! :-) - an elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Connor ! :)